# Strange character added when decoding with urllib

Tags: python, casting, urllib, unicode-string, python-3.10

I'm trying to parse a query string like this:
`filename=logo.txt\\x80\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x01x&filename=.hidden.txt`

Since it mixes bytes and text, I tried to alter it such that it will produce the desired escaped url output like so:

```
    extended = 'filename=logo.txt\\x80\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x01x&filename=.hidden.txt'
    fixbytes = bytes(extended, 'utf-8')
    fixbytes = fixbytes.decode("unicode_escape")
    algoext = '?' + urllib.parse.quote(fixbytes, safe='?&=')
```

This outputs
`b'filename=logo.txt\\x80\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x01x&filename=.hidden.txt'`

`filename=logo.txtx&filename=.hidden.txt`

`?filename=logo.txt%C2%80%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%01x&filename=.hidden.txt`

Where does the %C2 byte come from? It's not in the source string and it's not in any of the intermediate steps. What could I do other than manually remove it from the final output string?

P.S. I'm relying on a library to generate the string so changing the way it's represented initially is not an option.

Comment: My bad, the string is actually escaped, so it would be ```filename=logo.txt\\x80\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x01x&filename=.hidden.txt```

Comment: `'\x80'` encodes to `b'\xc2\x80'` with the default encoding, i.e., UTF-8. The string will be encoded to the default encoding before URL-quotes (as the urllib.parse documentation mentions: "Note that quote(string, safe, encoding, errors) is equivalent to quote_from_bytes(string.encode(encoding, errors), safe).". Since hex 80 already requires two bytes in UTF-8, you get the C2 byte in front of it. See the [examples on the Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Examples).

Comment: The question is more about how to do this properly, without introducing extra bytes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also achieves my goal:

```py
querystring = '?' + extended.replace('\\x', '%')
```

Answer (score 1):

As [the docs for urllib.parse.quote](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.quote) say

> Note that quote(string, safe, encoding, errors) is equivalent to quote_from_bytes(string.encode(encoding, errors), safe).

Where encoding defaults to UTF-8. And the UTF-8 encoding of '\x80' is...

```
>>> '\x80'.encode('utf-8')
b'\xc2\x80'
```

So it's correct that the %C2 is there. You shouldn't remove it.

Comment: Well that's all good, but I want to encode just the bytes. My query string obviously won't work with \xc2 at the start. Do you have another way of doing this?

Comment: "obviously"? Have you tried it? I'd argue any server that doesn't accept UTF-8 nowadays is broken.

Comment: Yes, I have tried it.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is what you want:

```
>>> extended = 'filename=logo.txt\\x80\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x01x&filename=.hidden.txt'
>>> fixbytes = bytes(extended, 'utf-8')
>>> fixbytes = fixbytes.decode("unicode_escape")
>>> fixbytes = fixbytes.encode("latin-1")
>>> fixbytes
b'filename=logo.txt\x80\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01x&filename=.hidden.txt'
>>> algoext = '?' + urllib.parse.quote(fixbytes, safe='?&=')
>>> algoext
'?filename=logo.txt%80%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%00%01x&filename=.hidden.txt'
```

Latin-1 is a legacy encoding that maps the codepoints 0-255 to the bytes 0-255. But really: If this is what you need, you should fix both whatever arcane process produced your mojibake in the first place AND the server that doesn't accept UTF-8 in 2022.